# Gtk#: is ConfigurationManager thread-safe?

Tags: c#, networking, configuration

I have to get some application's config from configuration file by one thread and to set by other thread (I'll get new config from network). I think, I can use ConfigurationManager by two threads at the same time, but is it safe and what is the best way for do it?

Comment: have you tried it yet?

Comment: No, I don't, but I'll